# Load large google docs faster

Tags: google-drive

I am using a gdoc quite often on my android smartphone. It's my basic ToDo-List. I have even put it on `Keep on device`.

However, the gdocs is still so large, so that it takes up to 5 minutes to load the doc.

Any recommendations how to fasten this process up?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: Apple, Android, Other? It probably belongs on another site as this is not a computer question...

Comment: @AthomSfere Oh sorry, I updated my answer! If the question is not related to superuser, pls feel free to suggest another stackoverflow site?

Comment: there is an Android site. It should be moved there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use an dedicated app instead of a browser (if appliable), and remove formatting from document.

Consider upgrading to a cellphone with more memory.